# Powershell - Scripts runs in ISE as expected. When calling from command line it errors

Tags: powershell

I have a script that calls an internal API. It gets passed a token and a json body.

When I hard code the parameters (token and json_body) in ISE, it runs great. As soon as I run from the command line, it bombs. I get an error **"Can't process argument because the argument "name" is not valid.**"

Just a note. The param $json_body can be ***very*** large.

Here is my script. Super simple and works as expected

```
PARAM($json_body, $token)

$json_body = 
'{
     "field1" : "1",
     "field2" : "2",
     "data" : [{<json data here>}]
}'

$header = @{'Token' = '1234567890* '}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <uri-here> -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $json_body
```

Here's the command I'm using

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -inputformat none -file "C:\PowerShell\Call_Rest_API_And_Post.ps1" -token <token_text> -json_body <json_body_text>
```

I'm passing data from an ETL process to push data to parameters, but if I run this directly from PowerShell (not ISE) I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : An unknown error occurred. Please see server logs for details.
At C:\PowerShell\Call_Rest_API_And_Post.ps1:5 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <uri-here> ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any pointers?

Comment: First thing I see is that you're overriding your `-json_body` parameter with the local variable `$json_body`. Second thing I see is that you are not using a proper heredoc string when you define `$json_body` in your script. Not sure if either of these would cause your issue but try fixing those in case they are contributing to your issue.

Comment: The error makes it look like you didn't change the -Uri argument.  It's reflecting `<uri_here>` Not sure...

Comment: Steven, <uri_here> is just a placeholder in this instance. I didn't want to share any internal uri names

Comment: You have an end-quote after the file path, but there is no start-quote?

Comment: Thanks Theo. Typo when formatting code for this help request

Comment: Are you escaping your json passed to `-json_body`?  Otherwise your script is getting more arguments than you think it is.